# Why is this Scala Maven POM file isn't good?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar

I got a new Spark app I'm writing with Scala on Maven, and I just found out I can't even run a "Hello World" for some reason. While compilation works fine trying to run the jar itself ends up with an error.

**EDIT:** Removed `<scope>provided</scope>` from dependencies, getting another error.

This is the POM file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.app</groupId>
<artifactId>deviceScore</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Device Score</name>

<properties>
    <spark.version>1.6.2</spark.version>
    <app.main.class>com.app.deviceScore.App</app.main.class>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>scala-2.10</id>
        <properties>
            <scala.version>2.10.6</scala.version>
            <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>scala-2.11</id>
        <properties>
            <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
            <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-repo</id>
        <name>Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>s3.release</id>
        <url>s3://clojure-deps/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-repo</id>
        <name>Apache release repo</name>
        <url>https://github.com/adatao/mvnrepos/tree/master/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>protoc-plugin</id>
        <url>http://sergei-ivanov.github.com/maven-protoc-plugin/repo/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.11</version>

    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>-Xms256m</jvmArg>
                    <jvmArg>-Xmx2048m</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${app.main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The App is as simple as:

```
package com.app.deviceScore

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println ("Hi!")
  }
}
```

When I run `mvn clean package -P scala-2.11` the build goes fine, but when I try to run the jar I get using `java -jar target/deviceScore-1.0.0.jar` i get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.deviceScore.App
```

When trying `scala target/deviceScore-1.0.0.jar` I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.deviceScore.App
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:63)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
        at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.run(MainGenericRunner.scala:13)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runJar(MainGenericRunner.scala:25)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:69)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

What am I missing? What else is supposed to be included in the POM file in order to simply run the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. In the plugins section, I used these three:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${app.main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${app.main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

The first one is different than the `scala-maven-plugin` used in the previous pom file. The second plugin makes the jar executable when using `scala target/deviceScore-1.0.0.jar`, and the third as mentioned by Tzach Zohar creates a fat jar which is executable with `java -jar target/deviceScore-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin is deprecated since several years and replaced by net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin as you used at first. (I'm the creator of both plugin). to fix you our original issue using the assembly plugin should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined `scala-library` (and other Scala dependencies) as `provided` - which means they don't get packaged in the jar, but are rather expected to be *provided* at runtime externally, and yet they are not - hence these classes are missing at runtime.

If you remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from all dependencies (perhaps `scala-compiler` can remain `provided`), this should work.

**EDIT**: 
Per your update - not sure why you get that specific error (main class should be found), but seems like there's more to be fixed here: when you use maven's `maven-jar-plugin`, it builds the jar *without* including its dependencies, which means you still won't have Scala's classes available.

Instead you can use maven's `maven-assembly-plugin` which can create a "fat jar", *with its dependencies* included. Do that by replacing the jar plugin with:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>${app.main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assemble-all</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, run:

```
> mvn clean package -P scala-2.11
> java -jar target/deviceScore-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Hi!
```

Comment: thanks - did that, now getting: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.deviceScore.App`. See the edit

Comment: @shakedzy see updated answer - I didn't get the same error as you did, but with the suggested changes to pom file your code worked for me, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

To run a Scala program packaged in a runnable jar file, use the `scala` command instead of `java -jar`:

```
scala target/deviceScore-1.0.0.jar
```

If you want to run it with `java -jar`, then you must make sure that the Scala library is included in the classpath. By setting the scope of the Scala library to `provided`, you excluded it from the runtime classpath.

Comment: thanks - did that, now getting: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.deviceScore.App`. See the edit

Comment: What did you do - run it with `scala` or add the Scala library to the classpath ? A Scala `object App` is not compiled into a Java class `App`, it gets a different name, so if you tell Java to run `com.app.deviceScore.App` then it cannot find it.

Comment: Both fail, `java -jar` and `scala`. I added that to the question

Comment: @shakedzy Maybe you should use the Scala plugin for Maven: [Scala with Maven](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html)

Comment: @jepser Added it, getting : `[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ deviceScore --- [WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!`